# mysql result show first some products, then the rest

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a mysql table like this one (it's an example):

```
| ID | Product name | Price | TopProduct |
| 01 | Product 001  | 10.00 |     1      |
| 02 | Product 002  | 15.00 |     0      |
| 03 | Product 003  | 20.00 |     1      |
| 04 | Product 004  | 10.00 |     0      |
```

Where **TopProduct** is a flag that the user set on the admin system.

The products that have the flag (**TopProduct**) set to 1, should appear first on the list and then, after the query bring me all the flagged, it would then show the other products ordered by "**ID**"

So in the end result i would have a list like this:

- Product 003
- Product 001
- Product 004
- Product 002

The question is, how should i put together my query or queries?
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: What did your reading of the documentation reveal to you so far? Or your MySQL book? This is pretty basic stuff :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT ID, ProductName, Price FROM product ORDER BY TopProduct, ID DESC
```

It will first order by TopProduct, Then again based on the ID

Comment: This worked pretty good. 
Actually a newbie mistake, didn't know i could ORDER BY multiple fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
ORDER BY `TopProduct`, `ID` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved this way:

```
select ProductName from table
order by TopProduct desc
```

**HOWEVER**, this will only work under the condition that TopProduct's max value is 1. I mean, if you can flag that column with a 2 in any row this won't work as that row will appear first. Is that the case?

In case it is, this is the query to sort all 1 at first regardless of the presence of any other number in the column:

```
select ProductName from table
order by if(TopProdct = 1, 1, 0) desc
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked too, but i find it more simple just to multiple ORDER BY... Thanks